# How do I hide Android keypad after a button is pressed until user taps an EditText box?

Tags: java, android

*Showing* the soft keypad at app start is easily done. But when the Show `Button` (`btnShow`) is clicked, I want to hide the keypad until the user taps an `EditText` box. This is because the keypad hides most of the output. And while it's not too much to ask the user to hide the keypad, I'd rather it just happen automatically.

But I can't make that happen. As shown, only 3 of 12 "combos" are visible.

[image]

Here's the relevant part of my main `Activity` Java code.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

       @Override protected void
                                  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // The next line shows the keypad on app creation:

          getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);


          final Button  bs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
                        bs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(View v) {

    // The next hides the keypad, but something else makes it re-appear immediately:

// *************** EDIT ******************
                    if(comb.size() > 0) {
                      b.setText(ss);
                      b.requestFocus();
                    }
// *************** END OF EDIT ***********
      getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        }
     });  
    }
  }
```

*** EDIT ***
After adding the 3 lines above, I've made some progress, but the alpha keypad is visible and the dialog scrolls off the screen:

[image]

**I've hidden the numeric keypad; how do I get rid of the alpha keypad to prevent scrolling?**

Here's the xml for the yellow output:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txvCombos"
    android:text="@string/default_combo"

    android:editable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:textColor="#fffbff32"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:lines="13"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"/>
```

(Original question: What do I do to hide the keypad when the SHOW button is tapped but allow the "combos" output to be viewed until user taps in an EditText box?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code when button clicked

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Is `getView()` a method I'm supposed to define? That's causing error with no suggestion about import or anything else. I'm REALLY new at Android, so bear with me, please. Having said that, I've tried a variation of that with no success. Using Android Studio 0.8.1.

Comment: The code was for fragment, now i chaged the second line. getView() to view.getApplicationWndowToken().
Please check it, thank you

Comment: @iravul--YOU ROCK! THANK YOU! I have to ask: WHERE did you FIND that?? I followed a dozen links, each with "answered" questions, but none worked--until YOURS!

Comment: oh great if it helped you. You can search with these terms "hide keyboard android". Thank you

Comment: @iravul--Now I feel like an idiot. I'm sure I found that link but I guess I just couldn't figure out how to make it work in the context of MY app. My knowledge base must be awfully shaky if that's all it took to stop me. NOW it's obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the view variable below the `OnClickListener`

```
public View view;
```